# How do I apply this javascript to the selected image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-animate, mouseover

I have this javascript applied to my webpage:

```
$(function() {

$('img.gallery_left').mouseover(function(){

    $('img.gallery_left').animate({
borderWidth: '10px',
width: '750px',
height: '500px',
marginLeft: '1px',
zIndex: '15'}, 'default');

});

$('img.gallery_left').mouseout(function(){

    $('img.gallery_left').animate({
borderWidth: '4px',
width: '300px',
height: '200px',
marginLeft: '1px'}, 'default');

    });
});
```

I have the gallery_left class applied to a number of images and when I hover over one of the images, it makes every single image with the class gallery_left increase in size, border, etc.  How do I make it so that *only* the image being hovered over is applied, or do I have to make every single image it's own class? (which I'd rather not have to do...)

P.S.  I'm not very fluent in JavaScript, (I'm surprised I made it this far!!) so just a heads up if I don't understand immediately what you're trying to get across.

Comment: Use `$(this).animate({ // ... })`. `$('img.gallery_left').mouseout` will bind an event to every image with the class of "gallery_left".  `$(this)` refers to the current DOM object that triggered the event, in this case the image being hovered over.

Answer (score 3):

Within the event handlers, replace `$('img.gallery_left')` with `$(this)`, e.g.:

```
$('img.gallery_left').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({...});
});
```

They will then only affect the specific element that saw the event, instead of the entire class of elements.